# How would I create a Look-up table containing the transfer function for increasing/decreasing the brightness of an image in a given amount

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a function that returns a Look-up table containing the transfer function for increasing/decreasing brightness as follows;

```
if inputvalue < -c
    outputvalue = 0
else if inputvalue > 255 - c
    outputvalue = 255
else
    outputvalue = inputvalue + c
```

Here is my attempt...

```
function Lut = brightnessLUT(c)

if c < -c 
    Lut = 0;
else if c > 255 - c
    Lut = 1:256;
else
    Lut = 1:c + c;
end

Lut = uint8(Lut);
end
```

Would this be correct? When I use another function I to enhance an inputted image with the amount of c it doesn't seem to affect the brightness at all and the inputted image just stays the same. Any help would be great.

```
function Iout = enhanceBrightness(Iin,c)
Lut = brightnessLUT(c);
Iout = intlut(Iin,Lut);
end
```

Comment: why don't you use just `Iout = uint8(Iin+c)`?

Comment: Note that `if c < -c` is always false for positive `c`, and always true for negative `c`!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simpler without using `if` and `else`:

- Start with the nominal LUT `0:255`.
- Add `c` to the nominal LUT.
- Limit the result to range `[0, 255]` using `min` and `max`.
  Note: In MATLAB you don't need to limit the range to [0, 255], because `uint8(Lut)` does it implicitly.

Here is the code:

```
function Lut = brightnessLUT(c)
    Lut = (0:255) + c;
    % Note: In MATLAB you don't need to limit the range to [0, 255], because uint8(Lut) does it implicitly.  
    Lut = max(min(Lut, 255), 0); %Limit Lut to range [0, 255].
    Lut = uint8(Lut);
end
```

In general, it's a good practice to use `min` and `max` for thresholding.

I added the thresholding code because I assume you are going to use it as preparation for implementation in other programming language (or just for learning how to build a LUT in general).

Comment: If casting to `uint8`, the clamping to the `[0,255]` range is implicit, and need not be added explicitly. `Lut = uint8((0:255) + c);` would do it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, sure..., I added the thresholding code, just for showing how to build a LUT in the general case (building a LUT is not needed anyway). I added comments to the post.

Comment: Of course, it's good to be explicit. It's a good answer. I just wanted to leave that comment there for completeness.